# how can i assign a material to my selected vertices on one object to multiple objects?

Tags: materials

I can assign my material in edit mode by selecting my faces, then select my material, then tap "assign".

But i cannot figure out how to do this to multiple objects?

My objects are all the same...just copies.

So i want all the same faces to be selected on my multiple objects and then the same material should be assigned. I know i can use the same material for all with CTRL-L, but i don't know how to do that "assign" thing in edit mode for **multiple** objects.

Comment: it's not clear, if all your objects share the same mesh (linked duplications aka Alt D), they will all get the same material on the same face, unless you've unlinked their material (objects can share the same mesh but each mesh can have its own material). If you've simply duplicated (Shift D) your objects don't share the same mesh

Comment: I'm afraid it'd be hard to implement this :). You're not actually assigning materials, just material *slots*, and every object can have different slots in different order ;). But I get you, i ran into the same issue yesterday :)

Comment: Not the same mesh…unfortunately